# Vtiger Crm : Add new module and associate with exsiting module

Tags: vtiger

I have created a new module for e.g. Resources Assigned and associated with existing module e.g Project through module designer (https://github.com/sardoj/VTModuleDesigner). Now i want to show new module 'Resources Assigned' in summary section of existing module 'Project'. I tried but is is not working properly. So what are the steps to show new added module in summary section of existing module.

Comment: Is any one who can help me out from this problem ???????

Answer (score 0):

you could use the related entities function on vtlib, this could work for you: 
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Vtlib_Related_Entities

also you need a field to relate the two modules

if you need more help, please let me know